# How to create a windowed application (like Brackets) with html/js?

Tags: html, native

I'm wondering how the guys from Brackets (https://github.com/adobe/brackets/) managed to make a native app with HTML5. They're probably using a library of any kind, but which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea is to ship a browser as a standalone app.
Brackets use [Brackets shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/) which is a fork of [The Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)